# Autoincrementing one character in calculate field of ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro, python-parser

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have this set of points where I like an unique id (uid). The only thing they need to be unique is a counter of some sort at the end.

I have another field with some id that should be infront (number), so my expression would be something like:

```
"!number!"+ INCREMENT + "h"
```

Is this doable?

[image]

Comment: I usually create a Point_ID field as "OBJECT_ID +1" ... I do the +1 so that my first point is at 1 not 0. You can do these easily in Calculate Field or in ArcPy.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to add a counting number (does not matter if the value is unique or not, or number of unique values) then try:

Pre-logic:

```
count = 0
def uidcreator(a):
    global count
    count+=1
    return "{0}-{1}h".format(a,count)
```

Call with:

> uid=

```
uidcreator( !SOMEFIELDNAME!)
```